# Can't start selenium-webdriver on Karma suite

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, karma-runner

Can't start a selenium-webdriver throught Karma test suite. I have try it with PhantomJS, Firefox, Chrome... and nothing.

I'm working on node@v0.12.17.

This is my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],

    files: [
        'scrollManagerSpec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'scrollManagerSpec.js': ['browserify']
    },
    browserify: {
        debug: true
    },
    reporters: ['spec'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [ 'Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

And my spec:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

When I do karma start I get the following error:

```
05 11 2016 17:10:14.355:INFO [framework.browserify]: bundle built
05 11 2016 17:10:14.377:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at      http://localhost:9876/
05 11 2016 17:10:14.378:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with     unlimited concurrency
05 11 2016 17:10:14.383:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
05 11 2016 17:10:15.750:INFO [Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0)]:     Connected on socket /#wgKE-Jh8ijn40wwtAAAA with id 81166649
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
  at /tmp/node_modules/selenium-    webdriver/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:284:0 <- /tmp/ac81dc30945845a8ed368199573da3f2.browserify:22517

Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.412 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: Getting similar error: `Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function` for code in file `selenium-webdriver/_base.js`. Same setup: karma, browserify...